# MIPS program- Cannot able to input negative number from console window? my program stuck for negative number, but operate well for postive

Tags: mips

I am writing mips program using MARS IDE for integer division of two number. I am trying to give user input from console. For positive number program is working, but for negative number I believe program is not compiling. My question is, how can we input negative number from console window?

Comment: If you are using `syscall 5` to input the numbers, it works just fine for negative numbers (using MARS).